# rich snippets are OK after saving the product, but fails after a couple of minuttes, M2.3.4

Tags: magento2, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets, rich-snippets

Has anyone experienced one day that rich snippets test passes with no errors right after saving the product in admin panel in Magento 2.3 and then test fails after some minuttes? Trying to find the solution (or rather the reason for unexpected behaviour...) on G and everywhere else but with no luck. Anybody?

In most cases the price tag disappears from tag list under the second test.
I have absolutely no idea what's going on here. I can see there is no external module that handles rich snippets in admin.

Comment: Is it that the markup stops being added to your site after a few minutes?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Read more from [General structured data guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/sd-policies) of Google:

> **Important: Google does not guarantee that your structured data will
> show up in search results**, even if your page is marked up correctly
> according to the Rich Results Test. Here are some common reasons why:
>
> Using structured data enables a feature to be present, it does not
> guarantee that it will be present. The Google algorithm tailors search
> results to create what it thinks is the best search experience for a
> user, depending on many variables, including search history, location,
> and device type. In some cases it may determine that one feature is
> more appropriate than another, or even that a plain blue link is best.
>
> The structured data is not representative of the main content of the
> page, or is potentially misleading.
>
> The structured data is incorrect
> in a way that the Rich Results Test was not able to catch.
>
> The content
> referred to by the structured data is hidden from the user.
>
> The page
> does not meet the guidelines for structured data described here, the
> type-specific guidelines, or the general webmaster guidelines.

The last item on the list means that Google can view your structured data for rich results in SERP while following all of their **[SEO rules](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/beginner/seo-starter-guide)** and their **[content policies](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/10622781)**.